# JSON serialized object is having date in format 2006-10-04T19:49:49. Not able to deserialized it

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am using struts2 and serializing the object and passing it to JSP. From jsp I am again passing this object to java and trying to deserialize it using following code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
receiptDocument = objectMapper.readValue(receiptDocumentStr,new TypeReference<ReceiptDocument>(){});
```

The Object which is getting serialized has a property in Timestamp. So when its serialized the date is converted into following format 2006-10-04T19:49:49. But when I try to deserialize it, it gives exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Please suggest me how should I do deserialization of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as described [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling)

```
  objectMapper.setDateFormat(myDateFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do deserialization of JSON object which is sent to jsp using struts2 by following code

```
@Result(name = SUCCESS, type = JSON, params = {
"ignoreHierarchy", "false", "includeProperties","bookList\\[\\d+\\]\\..*})
```

But when I send this bookList to server using `jquery post` and try to deserialize it, it was not working. So I serialized it in following way

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setDateFormat(sd);
bookListJsonString=  mapper.writeValueAsString(bookList);
```

And in deserialization code its as follows

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().setDateFormat(sd);
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().disable(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES); //To avoid failure if there is no any class fields.                
List<BooksDocument> bookList =  objectMapper.readValue(bookListJsonString, new TypeReference<List<BooksDocument>>() {});
```

If anyone have better way to do it. Please post it.